# How to structure Express to always send Angular whilst protecting API routes?

Tags: node.js, express, express-jwt

On my node-express back-end, I want to always serve my Angular files UNLESS it is an API route. If it is an API route, then deal with it as such.

All API routes are protected, *except* `/api/signin`, `/api/changepass`.

How do I structure my code? I think the order of my code is wrong... I keep getting back an `UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found` from `express-jwt`.

Currently my code:

```
app.use(jwt({secret: secretKey}).unless({path: ['/api/signin', '/api/changepass']}));
app.use('/', [
    AuthRouter, 
    StructureRouter, 
    DataRouter, 
    ResultsRouter,
]);

// Serve angular unless it is a path for the acme-challenge for let's encrypt certificate
app.use(ServeAngular().unless({path: [/\/.well-known\/acme-challenge/i]}))
app.use(/\/.well-known\/acme-challenge/i, express.static(path.join(__dirname, '.well-known', 'acme-challenge'), {dotfiles:'allow'}));
```

Answer (score 0):

"want to always serve my Angular files UNLESS it is an API route"

Instead, you should return your Angular app on the root path or on a static path if called via HTTP GET method and let hash routing handle the routes in Angular. Node doesn't bother hash routing, so you could use them to navigate through your app.
Anyway on error you could redirect on error or login page

"All API routes are protected, except /api/signin, /api/changepass"

redirection, authentication and protection should be handled by express's middleware function (https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) in order to ensure authentication or redirection. Your application shouldn't be aware of which route should be protected or not.

"I keep getting back an UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found from express-jwt"

On your Angular code have you created the required interceptors in order to forward on each request the required jwt (as cookie or header)?

Comment: Say the user hits ```/something/that/does/not/exist```, i want to be able to return the Angular file and deal with the 404 with angular. If i serve angular only on the root path, then this wouldn't happen, right? I'd only be serving the file on a specific route, unless I misunderstand. 

On the second point, that's what I'm doing. I applied ```app.use``` with ```express-jwt```. Interceptors work fine.

Comment: yeah, but if you add a fallback path which redirects you to the homepage (/#/home).

just add `res.redirect('/');` in the last app.use of your express routing